# Why do the two ways of registering pretty printers differ?

Tags: gdb, pretty-print

I have this code:

```cpp
struct number
{
    int n;
};

int main()
{
    number n{5};
    const number & ref = n;
}
```

I want to pretty print the `number` struct. I will show two pretty printers I have made:

printer1:

```py
class Printer:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string(self):
        return str(self.val["n"])

def matcher(val):
    lookup_tag = val.type.tag
    if lookup_tag is None:
        return None

    if lookup_tag == "number":
        return Printer(val)

gdb.pretty_printers.append(matcher)
```

printer2:

```py
class Printer:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string(self):
        return str(self.val["n"])

def build_pretty_printer():
    pp = gdb.printing.RegexpCollectionPrettyPrinter("num")
    pp.add_printer("num", "^number$", Printer)
    return pp

gdb.printing.register_pretty_printer(None, build_pretty_printer())
```

The first printer uses the "old" way of registering pretty printers, the second uses the "new" way with `RegexpCollectionPrettyPrinter`.

When I print `ref` using the first pretty printer, GDB prints this:

```
$1 = (const number &) @0x7fffffffe0b8: 5
```

The second pretty printer prints this:

```
$1 = 5
```

The pretty printer itself (`Printer`) is identical in the two pretty printers. Only the way of registering it has changed. Why is the result different then? Why does the first pretty printer print `(const number &) @0x7fffffffe0b8`? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: If you use the `matcher`, then gdb gives the same value to the matcher multiple times, first the reference type `const number &`, and then again without the reference as just `const number`, for which your matcher then returns a pretty printer. But the `RegexpCollectionPrettyPrinter` already removes all references, typedefs, and const/volatile, then matches it with the name you provided.

Comment: Thanks @ssbssa! If you'll post this as an answer, I will accept it.